# Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception when trying create database codefirst

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am getting an Object reference not set to an instance of an object when I am trying to add new student but the student is not null.

I am trying to create mysql db with entity:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db =new MySqlTest())
            {
                var s = new Student() {id = 1,num = 9};
                db.Student.Add(s);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
    }

      public class Student
        {
            [Key]
            public long id { get; set; }
            public long num { get; set; }
        }

        [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
        public class MySqlTest : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
        }
```

stack trace

```
   ב-  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)    ב-  System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)    ב-  MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)    ב-  System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)    ב-  System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)    ב-  System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)    ב-  System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)    ב-  System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()    ב-  System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)    ב-  System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()    ב-  System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()   ב-  System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)    ב-  System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)    ב-  System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)    ב-  MySqlWithEF.Program.Main(String[] args) ב- C:\Users\X7\Desktop\MyExampls C#\MySqlWithEF\Program.cs:שורה 24    ב-  System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)    ב-  System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    ב-  Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()    ב-  System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)    ב-  System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    ב-  System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    ב-  System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    ב-  System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: nope its a mysql ef problem

Comment: Interesting... sorry about the mistaken duplicate. So am I correct in understanding that `db.Student` is not null when calling `db.Student.Add(s)`? Do you have a stack trace for us?

Comment: yes i added it you can look

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the body of your question so the content is not in quotes. Unless you are specifically quoting something, that is not needed. I also formatted the error in code formatting (4 spaces before it), it makes it easier to read. Good day!